# Find the range of a $4$th-degree function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the function $y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$, I see graphically that the range is $\ge-1$.  But I cannot find a way to determine the range algebraically?

Comment: It's a positive quartic with 4 roots, so you just need to find the 2 minima. However you have marked your question as "precalculus" so perhaps doing this graphically is the best option. Otherwise I would suggest differentiating.

Comment: The word "analytically" usually means by calculus. Are calculus means acceptable to you?

Answer (score 7):

**Non-calculus Approach/ Completing Square Approach**

Let $u=(x-2)(x-3)=x^2-5x+6$

$(x-1)(x-4)=x^2-5x+4=u-2$

So 
\begin{align}
y&=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\&=u(u-2)\\&=u^2-2u\\&=(u-1)^2-1
\end{align}

As $(u-1)^2\ge0$ for all $u\in{\Bbb{R}}$

$y\ge0-1=-1$