# Ways to find $\min[f(x)]$ where $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ without using derivatives

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, maxima-minima

As title states I need to:

> Find $\min[f(x)]$ where $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ without using derivatives

Since I i'm restricted to not use the derivatives I've started to play with the function in different ways. After some experiments I've noticed the following:

Let
$$
g(x) = (x-1)(x-3)
$$

and

$$
h(x) = (x-2)(x-4)
$$

Then i tried to find vertexes with $x_v = -{b \over 2a}$ and calculate values of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in $x_v$ points and they appear to be the minimum values for $f(x)$. I've also checked this for $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-5)(x-6)$ and a lot of other similar polynomials. All of them are symmetric with respect to some $x$.

Based on the above the $\min[f(x)] = -1$ and $\min[g(x)] = -4$ but I'm not sure why this worked. Could someone explain me what happened? I would 
also appreciate if anyone could tell whether there exists a general way of finding minimum for even power polynomials of the following kind:

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(x-k)
$$

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x+5/2)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295586/find-the-range-of-a-4th-degree-function/1295619#1295619

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** You can exploit symmetry. Note the zeroes are equally spaced, so their center is $$\tfrac{1+2+3+4}{4}=\tfrac{10}{4}=\tfrac{5}{2}$$
This means you can write
$$f(x)=(x-\tfrac52-\tfrac32)(x-\tfrac52-\tfrac12)(x-\tfrac52+\tfrac12)(x-\tfrac52+\tfrac32)$$
$$=\left((x-\tfrac52)^2-(\tfrac32)^2\right)\left((x-\tfrac52)^2-(\tfrac12)^2\right)$$
$$=(z-\tfrac94)(z-\tfrac14)$$
where $z=(x-\tfrac52)^2$. Now you can find the $z_0 \geq 0$ which minimizes this polynomial using symmetry (vertex of the parabola). Then $f(z_0)$ is the desired quantity.

Answer (score 10):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)
&=& (x^2-5x+4)(x^2-5x+6) \\
&=& (x^2-5x+5)^2-1 \\
&=& ((x-2.5)^2-1.25)^2-1 \\
&\ge& -1
\end{array}$$

Equality is achieved when $(x-2.5)^2 - 1.25 = 0$.